# Pass many-to-many object to variable

Tags: python, django, orm

I have 2 classes, with many-to-many relationship, my goal is to fill an 'item' list with data from that 2 models, here are my models:

```
class Bakery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('restaurant_name', max_length=100)


class DeliveryService(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('deliveryservice_name', max_length=100)
    bakery = models.ManyToManyField(Bakery)
```

Here is the logic on my 'views' file:

```
item = []
bakerys = Bakery.objects.all()

for i in bakerys:
    item.append(i.title)
    item.append(i.deliveryservice.title)
```

I hope you got what exactly I want to accomplish. My current 'views' file logic is wrong and I know it, I just does not know what can I do to solver this problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: For one thing, your classes don't inherit from anything. Typically, they should inherit from `models.Model` I suggest reading the official tutorial and documentation, as it will answer your question. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/

Comment: Of course they inherit from 'models.Model', I prefered to not put them here for not distract from main point

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here.. is it just `Bakery.objects.values('title', 'deliveryservice__title')`?

Comment: You want a list. OK, but is there any order ? Or It doesn't matter ?

Comment: I want to fill my 'item' list with 2 variables, first: title of Bakery, second: title of DeliveryService, which is many-to-many to Bakery, but when I'm doing this like above, I keep getting object has no attribute '__getattr__' error

Comment: I need to explain what you really want in `item`.  Do you want it to be a list with the first item to be the name of the Bakery and then all the other items being the name of the delivery services associated with it?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to do what you're asking for.  But it seems odd that you want to create a list with all the titles for different objects all mixed together and likely have duplicates (if a delivery service is linked to more than one bakery it'll be added twice).

```
item = []
bakerys = Bakery.objects.all()

for i in bakerys:
    item.append(i.title)
    for j in i.deliveryservice_set.all():
        item.append(j.title)
```

You should really read up on the [many-to-many functionality of the ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).  The documentation is pretty clear on how to do these things.

Sayse had a good answer too if you really just want all the titles.  Their answer also groups everything in tuples and accomplishes it with more efficiency by using fewer db queries.  Their answer was:  `Bakery.objects.values('title', 'deliveryservice__title')`